# Reshape features in rows intro columns python?

Tags: python, reshape, crosstab

My features are arranged in rows, Can anyone tell me please how can I transform them into columns with theirs corresponding times and values??
I mean each features has a set of corresponding times and values ..
a view example of   dataset is :

```
Feature                      TIME                     Value
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:05:18.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:06:18.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:10:08.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:13:18.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:26:28.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:31:48.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T05:07:28.0
        .
.......
   YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T03:36:22.000Z          42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T07:23:31.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T11:30:12.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-29T03:16:42.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-29T06:56:12.000Z           42
```

Comment: It looks like you tried to upload a photo of your data (which didn't show up). In any case, please show us data in text, as we can't cut and paste images

Comment: is it clear now ? I edited my question ..

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a numpy array, you can use:

```
my_rearranged_data = my_data.T
```

which computes the transpose of the matrix. If your data is in a pandas dataframe, use:

```
my_rearranged_data = my_data.transpose()
```

Comment: Note that `my_data.T` will work for a `pandas` dataframe too

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Maybe what you need to do is only transpose a subset of your data matrix?